# will storing pointers in array benefit from CPU cache speed up?

Tags: c, performance, caching, c++11

As far as I know, in theory if I store data in continuous memory, for example an array, when the first element of the array is read by cpu, because of striding, cpu can load the entire array to its L1 cache(if the array can fit in L1 cache), therefore reducing cache miss when reading the other array elements.

But what if the array stores pointers, and cpu has to dereference the pointer and perform some operations on it, which will lead to other part of memory being loaded to L1 cahce. 
For example if my L1 data cache is 32KB, and I have an array of 8K elements:

```
MyObject* myarray[8192];
//...
for (int i=0; i < 8192; ++i) {
    MyObject& obj = *myarray[i];
    obj.doSomethingComplicated();
}
```

In this case the total size of myarray will be 4x8 = 32KB, am I right at least part of the L1 cache will likely to be trashed when doSomethingComplicated() is performed? And therefore trying to limit myarray size so that it can fit in a L1 cache is pointless?

In reality, I can still see a small but repeatedly measurable performance increase when choosing a relatively small size for myarray, but I can't really explain why.

I'm only concerned about x86_64 as I'm totally unfamiliar with other platforms.

Comment: Don't ignore the very real possibility that the measured speed improvements are due to L2 and L3 cache. While not as fast as L1, they're still much faster than main memory.

Comment: The performance will degrade with the number of touched cache lines (reading a bit from a cache line is as costly as reading all in the cache line). So if your MyObject is large and your code touches small data objects all around in the object you will touch lots of cache lines. If you only touch a couple of data members and these are located near each other the number of cache lines touched would be far less.

Comment: you are quite right, I do have 256K L2 cache on the machine and haven't tried array big enough to not fit in L2 cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple answer.

1. Caches work with areas of memory called *cache lines*. For modern Intel CPUs a cache line has 64 bytes, and this is what the cache will operate on (load, store). So it won't probably load all you array to cache, even though it fits.
2. There is a separate L1 caches for data and instructions. In your case, `myarray` will be loaded to data cache, but code for the function will be loaded into instruction cache. The code of the function is shared between all objects of a class, so unless polymorphism is used, the code will be loaded once to the cache.
3. There are of course members of the class. The `doSomethingComplicated` method probably operates on them, so the data has to be loaded into the (data) cache, again, in 64B chunks. The layout of the data the method operates on will thus matter.

All in all, my recommendation would be: given the information above, do some experiments and measure performance for your case.

Comment: thanks, in my case polymorphism will be used, that's the main reason to store a pointer. As I understand the cpu will try to load more than one cache line if it thinks that will reduce cache miss, and it usually does so when accessing an array. I do see a small performance advantage to use a small sized array, but not quite sure why. If I'm storing a polymorphism pointer and operating on its members then some part of the data cache is bound to be overwritten and therefore I would think it doesn't matter if the entire array can fit or not.

Comment: Modern Intel CPUs have a load predictor. It will indeed not load the whole array into cache, but the 64 byte cache line is probably not what will be loaded either. Details, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can be nearly certain that parts of your pointer array gets pushed out of L1 if 'doSomethingComplicated' touches *any* memory. The evicted uses a pseudo LRU algorithm, the pseudo part is that it happens on a set bases, ie. cachelines that share the lowest part of the address.

Your array of pointers is fine (if you like pointers) and it will in this case operate in near optimal fashion as it will be used sequentially, **but** your problem will be what it points too which should also be accessed sequentially for best performance.

That means the 'MyObject' would optimally be in an array itself, in which case the original pointers gets pointless! as indexes would be as good or rather much better.

```
MyObject MyObjectArray[8192];
```

If they are not accessed sequentially you are potentially in pointer chasing territory which is bad. But at least they have some spatial locality as they occupy a continuous memory region.

The level 1 cache uses 2 pre-fetchers that makes continuous memory access really well behaving, effectively making all memory access through them at L1 latency. In the newest Intel L2 cache can service 2 memory requests from L1, but only get one from L3 each cycle, L3 services all L2 caches so they must queue up if more than one request is made each cycle. L3 can only be served by other L3(or L4) caches or memory at one request every X cycles.

So as long as myarray and MyObjectArray *and* all other memory 'doSomethingComplicated' or functions it calls touches can fit in L2 your program will run very fast. As soon as you need 3 pre-fetchers or go to L3/memory all will slow down.

So everything unsurprisingly depends on the behaviour of 'doSomethingComplicated'.

Comment: I think you mean "locality of reference" instead of localization. The latter is a step in translating software.

Comment: As edited, it starts of wrong. Cache _lines_ are invalidated, and it's unlikely that `doSomethingComplicated` invalidates all cache lines. The majority of operations in fact will replace at most one cache line.

Comment: @MSalters, corrected the first, but what do you mean 'Cache lines are invalidated' I don't (yet) talk about cache lines.

Comment: Well, if you say that "the array is pushed out", you're suggesting it is an atomic entity which is either in the cache or not.

Comment: @MSalters, clarified pushed out :)